# fail2ban wont ban ssh from local hosts

Tags: linux, ssh, fail2ban

I'm trying to configure fail2ban to block ssh from a local hosts. Fail2ban is install on CentOS 7 with firewall (Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64 ). I have copied the jail.conf to jail.local i have change the following parameters in jail.local:

```
banaction = firewallcmd-new
[sshd]
enabled = true
maxretry = 5
port = ssh
logpath = /var/log/secure
action = firewallcmd-ipset
```

And i have no results. Any idea ?

Some log info:

```
Jun 23 07:21:33 localhost.localdomain fail2ban-client[2486]: 2015-06-23 07:21:33,351 fail2ban.server         [2487]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.9.1
Jun 23 07:21:33 localhost.localdomain fail2ban-client[2486]: 2015-06-23 07:21:33,351 fail2ban.server         [2487]: INFO    Starting in daemon mode
Jun 23 07:21:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Fail2Ban Service.

2015-06-23 07:14:27,571 fail2ban.server         [1926]: INFO    Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.9.1
2015-06-23 07:14:27,710 fail2ban.database       [1926]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2015-06-23 07:14:27,788 fail2ban.jail           [1926]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
2015-06-23 07:14:27,923 fail2ban.jail           [1926]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses poller
2015-06-23 07:14:27,985 fail2ban.filter         [1926]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
2015-06-23 07:14:27,985 fail2ban.jail           [1926]: INFO    Initiated 'polling' backend
2015-06-23 07:14:28,063 fail2ban.filter         [1926]: INFO    Added logfile = /var/log/secure
2015-06-23 07:14:28,064 fail2ban.filter         [1926]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 2
2015-06-23 07:14:28,066 fail2ban.filter         [1926]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
2015-06-23 07:14:28,066 fail2ban.actions        [1926]: INFO    Set banTime = 86400
2015-06-23 07:14:28,067 fail2ban.filter         [1926]: INFO    Set findtime = 600
2015-06-23 07:14:28,068 fail2ban.filter         [1926]: INFO    Set maxlines = 10
2015-06-23 07:14:28,158 fail2ban.server         [1926]: INFO    Jail sshd is not a JournalFilter instance
2015-06-23 07:14:28,459 fail2ban.jail           [1926]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
2015-06-23 07:21:32,667 fail2ban.server         [1926]: INFO    Stopping all jails
2015-06-23 07:21:33,181 fail2ban.jail           [1926]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' stopped
2015-06-23 07:21:33,188 fail2ban.server         [1926]: INFO    Exiting Fail2ban
2015-06-23 07:21:33,404 fail2ban.server         [2489]: INFO    Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.9.1
2015-06-23 07:21:33,406 fail2ban.database       [2489]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2015-06-23 07:21:33,409 fail2ban.jail           [2489]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
2015-06-23 07:21:33,413 fail2ban.jail           [2489]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses poller
2015-06-23 07:21:33,433 fail2ban.filter         [2489]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
2015-06-23 07:21:33,433 fail2ban.jail           [2489]: INFO    Initiated 'polling' backend
2015-06-23 07:21:33,438 fail2ban.filter         [2489]: INFO    Added logfile = /var/log/secure
2015-06-23 07:21:33,439 fail2ban.filter         [2489]: INFO    Set maxRetry = 3
2015-06-23 07:21:33,440 fail2ban.filter         [2489]: INFO    Set jail log file encoding to UTF-8
2015-06-23 07:21:33,441 fail2ban.actions        [2489]: INFO    Set banTime = 86400
2015-06-23 07:21:33,442 fail2ban.filter         [2489]: INFO    Set findtime = 600
2015-06-23 07:21:33,442 fail2ban.filter         [2489]: INFO    Set maxlines = 10
2015-06-23 07:21:33,501 fail2ban.server         [2489]: INFO    Jail sshd is not a JournalFilter instance
2015-06-23 07:21:33,599 fail2ban.jail           [2489]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
```

And SELinux is disabled.

Comment: What on earth would you need to firewall off as a fail2ban from local host on ssh for..? We can answer more effectively if you clarify this

Comment: check http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ_english to make sure fail2ban works well, also check user and root timezone

Answer (score 0):

In the file below,

`/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` (note if you are using `jail.local` the same can be applied there also)
try changing `auto` to `gamin` or `polling`

**Note:** 
if `systemd` backend is chosen as the default but you enable a jail
for which logs are present only in its own log files, specify some other
backend for that jail (e.g. polling) and provide empty value for
`journalmatch`. See https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/959#issuecomment-74901200

So, changing

```
backend = auto
```

to

```
backend = gamin
```

or

```
backend = polling
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/secure /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
```

It should has n matched. If not check your failregex.

Then run

```
sudo fail2ban-client set loglevel DEBUG
```

Check `fail2ban.log` to see if it accesses sshd logfile(auth.log or secure).

If above are OK, please check timezone, fail2ban use system timezone, if log file doesn't use, it cause findtime out of action.